# Does FFMPEG's Concat demuxer need identical stream structures?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to concatenate three mp4 video files. The first and last are videos I have created in FFMPEG that consist of a series of title and credit slides. The centre video is a recording taken from a BlackMagic HyperDeck.

However, following concatenating the centre video is always compressed, almost as if it has been changed to the wrong framerate. I have tried as best possible to create the title and ending videos using identical settings to the source; a requirement of the concat demux - the only big difference I can see at this point is that the main video has three streams; The video, a timecode data stream and the audio. The title slides however have two streams.

Could the timecode be the source of my issues, with somehow FFMPEG trying to concatenate the Audio of the title stream with the data stream of the main video?

**Command used to create the title video**

*note: for now I'm just using a null audio; I want to get to the stage of having audio in this file. You can also see that I have tried to create a video file with the exact same framerate and timescale and audio rate as the source.*

```
ffmpeg.exe -loop 1 -r 59.94 -t 5 -i intro0.png
           -loop 1 -r 59.94 -t 5 -i intro1.png 
           -f lavfi -i anullsrc
           -s 1920x1080 -filter_complex 
           "[1]format=yuva444p,fade=d=1:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+4/TB[f0];
            [0][f0]overlay[bg1],format=yuv420p[v]"
            -map "[v]" -map 2:a -c:v libx264 
            -b:v 1000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -video_track_timescale 60000 
            -c:a aac -ar 48000 -ac 2 -sample_fmt fltp -t 8 intro.mp4
```

**FFProbe output from intro**

```
ffprobe.exe intro.mp4
ffprobe version git-2020-08-31-4a11a6f Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.1 (GCC) 20200805
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass
--enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 58.100 / 56. 58.100
  libavcodec     58.101.101 / 58.101.101
  libavformat    58. 51.101 / 58. 51.101
  libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
  libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'intro.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.51.101
  Duration: 00:00:10.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1061 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1167 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94
tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

**FFProbe output from HyperDeck Recording**

```
ffprobe.exe test1.mp4
ffprobe version git-2020-08-31-4a11a6f Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.1 (GCC) 20200805
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass
--enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 58.100 / 56. 58.100
  libavcodec     58.101.101 / 58.101.101
  libavformat    58. 51.101 / 58. 51.101
  libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
  libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: iso4avc1isom
    creation_time   : 2020-12-22T02:16:32.000000Z
    com.apple.proapps.reel: 1
    com.apple.proapps.scene: 1
    com.apple.proapps.shot: 176
    com.blackmagic-design.camera.environment: interior
    com.blackmagic-design.camera.dayNight: day
    com.apple.proapps.cameraName: A
    com.blackmagic-design.camera.dateRecorded: 20201222
  Duration: 00:00:43.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 21402 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 21265 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 120k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-12-22T02:16:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : H264/AVC
      timecode        : 01:24:19;30
    Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-12-22T02:16:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Time Code Media Handler
      timecode        : 01:24:19;30
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-12-22T02:16:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Sound Media Handler
      timecode        : 01:24:19;30
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 1
```

**Concat command used**

*test.concat has the absolute paths to the video files*

```
ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i test.concat -c copy -metadata title="Fri Test 12 Feb 2021" -metadata copyright="Me © 2021" -metadata year="2021" concatinated.mp4
```

**Background Context**
I'm controlling FFMPEG from a C# application that manages the BMD HyperDeck, a BMD Television Switcher and several other applications/devices from a single control surface. The goal is to produce at the end of an event a packaged recording that is good to go and copied onto multiple devices. I elected to use the concat demuxer as it doesn't require re-encoding any of the videos; the events can be up to two hours in length and I want to be able to slap the bookends on the video as fast as possible so people can get the SD cards as soon as possible. It's a bit of a compromise as I would love to be able to fade the titles in/out of the main Video, but my understanding is that that would need re-encoding which I don't have time for, so butting things up it is. I'm no FFMPEG expert and have put together what I have through searching and reading.

**Update 1**
As I mention in a comment to @llogan, I have confirmed that the embedded timecode data at stream 1 is messing up the concat. I removed this from the source using the command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i test1.mp4 -c copy -map v -map :2 out.mp4
```

and with @llogan's updated title command they concat with no issues. Is it possible though to perform this map during the concat so I don't have to add an extra step to the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Each segment must have (mostly) identical attributes to concat properly

You're close, you just need to match the H.264 Profile with `-profile:v main`:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 60000/1001 -t 5 -i intro0.png
       -loop 1 -framerate 60000/1001 -t 5 -i intro1.png 
       -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=48000:cl=stereo
       -filter_complex 
       "[0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=4,scale=1920:1080,format=yuv420p[v]"
        -map "[v]" -map 2:a -c:v libx264 -profile:v main
        -c:a aac -t 8 intro.mp4
```

Refer to a [list of which attributes need to match for proper concatenation](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/32603).

Changes to your command:

- Use `-framerate` input option instead of `-r` for the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1).
- The video from blackmagic is actually 60000/1001, not 59.94. Confusingly, `ffmpeg` reports an abbreviated frame rate. `ffprobe -show_streams input.mp4` will show the actual rate.
- Used the scale filter instead of `-s` and placed it in the filtergraph.
- Directly set the sample rate and channel layout in anullsrc instead of using `-ar` and `-ac`, but you can keep those options if you prefer.
- Used [xfade](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade) instead of format+fade+setpts+overlay.
- Removed `-b:v 1000k`. No need to manually declare a bitrate. The encoder libx264 will automatically provide an appropriate value. See the `-crf` option in [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).
- Removed `-pix_fmt yuv420p` as it is already being applied via `format=yuv420p`. `-pix_fmt yuv420p` is just an alias for `format=yuv420p`.
- Removed `-video_track_timescale 60000` because using `-framerate 60000/1001` should provide the proper timescale, but you can leave it if you prefer.
- Removed `-sample_fmt fltp` because `-c:a aac` only supports fltp. See `Supported sample formats` in `ffmpeg -h encoder=aac`.

Comment: thanks for the reply - I've switched to this to generate the titles but unfortunately it still didn't work. Your suggestions are much cleaner though (I assume that anullsrc**r** is a typo though?). I removed the timecode stream using the command ```ffmpeg.exe -i test1.mp4 -c copy -map v -map :2 out.mp4``` and was able to concat that file with no issues, so it does seem to be related to the timecode stream. Is there a way to tell the concat to ignore a stream?

Comment: @Dan Yes, it's a typo. Fixed. You can try adding the `-dn` input option to omit data streams in your concat command: `ffmpeg -dn -f concat -safe 0 -i test.concat ...`. If for some reason you must resort to re-muxing to exclude timecode data then use negative mapping: `ffmpeg -i test1.mp4 -map 0 -map -d -c copy out.mp4`

Comment: Strange; the ```-dn``` didn't work. I'll use the negative mapping you suggest. Thanks for getting this over the line.